# SAS sgpanel will center justify a footnote of more than two lines when a legend is present

Tags: graphics, sas, legend, line-breaks

I am generating a figure using sgpanel with a left justified footnote. The `justify=left` works when the footnote is either short enough to fit on a single line, or if the plot does not have a legend. But when the legend is too long, so a line break is automatically inserted, then the footnote becomes center justified. But only if there is a legend.

```
footnote1 justify=left "This footnote is two lines long in a plot created by sgpanel with a legend. Therefore, it will for some reason be center justified instead of left justified. ";

proc sgpanel data=sashelp.cars pctlevel=graph;
   panelby origin;
   where origin in("Asia" "Europe");
   vbar type / response=horsepower stat=percent
       group=cylinders;
run;
```

The result is:

[image]

I can get around this by breaking the footnote up in two myself (footnote1 and footnote2) each being left justified and shorter than one line. But why is this happening, and is there another way of getting around it?

Comment: I have no idea about the reason. If you're willing to change to `proc template`, you can use `entryfootnote "yourtext" /textfitpolicy=wrap;`.

Comment: Yes. Switching to ´proc template´ is another alternative. I have other figures build in prog template and sgplot, and I do not get the problems there. The issue seems to only be there in sgpanel when there is a legend. But instead of changing to prog template, then it is less work to just break up the footnote myself, even if it is not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your program in a generic SAS/EG session I don't see that behavior in the results window.  What is your ODS destination and SAS version.

SYSVLONG=9.04.01M6P110718

[image]

Comment: You need to have the footnote inside the image. 
In SAS EG you can under Tools->Options chose this under Results->Graph

Comment: But for the record, I have: SYSVLONG = 9.04.01M5P091317